# How do I resize and JPG decode a jpeg image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to resize a image to particular width and height and also I want to decode the JPG image. I am trying this using OpenCV. I am first resizing and then decoding the image, but getting an assertion error. Is there anything I am missing?

My code:

```
int main()
{
    string image_path = "input.jpg";
    Mat img = imread(image_path, IMREAD_COLOR);
    if(img.empty())
    {
        cout << "Could not read the image: " << image_path << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int out_w = 416;
    int out_h = 416;
    Mat resizedImage;
    resize(img, resizedImage, Size(out_w, out_h));

    Size s = resizedImage.size();
    printf("Image resized with height: %d, width: %d\n", s.height, s.width);

    Mat decoded = imdecode(resizedImage, 1);

    Size d = decoded.size();
    printf("Image decoded with height: %d, width: %d\n", d.height, d.width);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code:

Image resized with height: 416, width: 416
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  OpenCV(4.2.0) ../modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:732: error: (-215:Assertion failed) buf.checkVector(1, CV_8U) > 0 in function 'imdecode_'

Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Calling `decode` is incorrect here. `imread` already returns a decoded image. And you wouldn't be able to call resize on `encoded` data.

Comment: @ALX23z How do I do it then? Is ```img``` already a JPG decoded buffer?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. `img` is an image buffer decoded from a jpeg.